# Get number of characters that can be displayed in an EditText

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

My question is about Android/Java.

How can I get the number of characters that can be **displayed**, **not entered**, in an EditText?

If I create an error popup for an EditText with a text that is too long, a new line is not automatically created so that it fits the EditText size. That's why I have to manually create a new line after a certain number of letters.

```
b.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    e.setError("SO - Please enter a correct E-Mail!!!"); //too long, not showed correctly
                }
            });
```

Because of that, my question:
How can I get the number of characters that can be **displayed** (I'm **not** meaning **entered**) in an EditText?

Comment: You can add code to improve your question and have more precise answer.

Comment: @Babasile thanks for the tip

Comment: The number of characters that can be displayed will vary by what characters those are, for most typefaces. Are you using monospace?

Comment: @CommonsWare Can I check with a method if a string can be fully displayed in an EditText? How can I know if I am using monospace?

Comment: "How can I know if I am using monospace?" -- you would have configured the `EditText` to use that typeface. "Can I check with a method if a string can be fully displayed in an EditText?" -- yes, though I forget the details. `EditText` extends from `TextView`, and I am sure that there are recipes for doing that sort of measurement for a `TextView`.